# How to make 3D transition image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to make the 3D image with background. Looks like below

[image: image link]

Comment: I wouldn't call it 3D. In any case, I'm pretty sure the photos used for that are simply that shape. Or at least the part that is the person needs to be delivered with a transparent background.

Comment: In the example you give, it doesn't seem to have a 3D transform. What the images you receive look like at origin?

Comment: I just want same as above image, don't know how?? I received only png images and i want set image like above image with background